# Internal server error after setting up Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just set up a Rails project on Apache following [this](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rubygems_generic_install) and ran the following

```
1. (Create the project) rails new myproject

2. (Restart Apache Server) service apache2 restart

3. (Edit Gemfile) append "gem 'therubyracer'" (Without this gem, running the 'rake' command gives an error about JavaScript)

4. (Install Bundle) bundle install

5. (Create Database) rake db:create

6. (Generate Controller) rails generate controller sites new

7. (Migrate Database) rake db:migrate
```

All steps ran without problem. From Step 6, there are files set up in the controller and view, and the routes.rb file is modified. However, accessing `sites/new` on my website shows the `500.html` page (internal server error). I'm able to access files in the `public` directory just fine.

Why could that be? What should I check?

**EDIT**: I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in `production.rb` and I'm getting some error message. It says

```
`SQLite3::CantOpenException
unable to open database file`
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you pull the specific Rails error from your logs?

Comment: get the real error from the log files

Comment: Ah okay, I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in `production.rb` and I'm getting some error message. It says `SQLite3::CantOpenException

unable to open database file`